# Python Pandas - How to extract the left a series of characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

We have this:

```
def get_prices():
    prices = pd.read_json("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices")
    prices_df = pd.DataFrame(prices)
    prices_df["Asset"] = "??"
    prices_df["Quote"] = prices_df["symbol"].str.extract(r"(USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$")
    return prices_df
```

Returning this:

```
       price   symbol Asset Quote
0  0.0578730   ETHBTC    ??   BTC
1  0.0105800  LTCUSDT    ??  USDT
2  0.0019219    NBBTC    ??   BTC
3  0.0038840   NEOBNB    ??   BNB
4  0.0157500  QTUMETH    ??   ETH
```

The "symbol" here is a pair composed of "Asset"+"Quote" without any separation, and each can have different lenghts. But we know that the Quote symbols can only be 4: "USDT","BTC","ETH","BNB".

How do we define the "Asset" column in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract the prefix, given the list of all possible suffixes:

```
pattern = '(\w+)(USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$'
df[['Asset','Quote']] = df['symbol'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Comment: Updated the answer to calculate both columns simultaneously.